# Adding a <div class></div> that encloses other elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm editing a rather primitive forum, and it won't let me modify the HTML. I can only edit the CSS. So, I want to see if it would be possible to add a *<div class""></div>* in the HTML with JavaScript that encloses more of the existing elements.

The current HTML is as follows:

```html
<div class="details">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1r7oGBt.png"></div>
  <p><span class="u_title">None</span>
    <span class="u_rank"></span></p>
  <dl class="u_group"><dt>Group</dt>
    <dd>User</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="u_posts"><dt>Messages</dt>
    <dd>52</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="u_scoresystem rep_zero"><dt>Score System</dt>
    <dd>0</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="u_status"><dt>Estado</dt>
    <dd>Anónimo</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

And I would like it to be something like this, i.e. using *<div class="overlay">*</div>:

```html
<div class="details">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1r7oGBt.png"></div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <p><span class="u_title">None</span>
      <span class="u_rank"></span></p>
    <dl class="u_group"><dt>Group</dt>
      <dd>User</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="u_posts"><dt>Messages</dt>
      <dd>52</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="u_scoresystem rep_zero"><dt>Score System</dt>
      <dd>0</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="u_status"><dt>Estado</dt>
      <dd>Anónimo</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Your HTML codes are the same here, could you please clarify the answer?

Comment: In the second one I have included <div class="overlay"></div>.

Comment: it's tricky with js to wrap some arbitrary lines without something to select which there is nothing except `.details p, details.dl`. Is overlay really needed or cant you simply use `.details .u_title`, `.details .u_rank`, or if its to *overlay* traverse from `.details` and hide/show etc

Comment: In the main part of this page, your "`<div class="overlay"></div>`" was hidden (a "feature" of ***this site*** (Stack Overflow)). In the future, you need to change/format it so it shows up here. One way is to encode "`<`" as "[`&lt;`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography)".

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

1. Iterate over all elements with class `details`.
2. For each of those elements, destructure the children beyond the first child into a variable.
3. Create the surrounding element using `document.createElement`.
4. Append the surrounding element.
5. Append the elements you restructured in 2. to the new element.

Don't try to solve the problem by copying some HTML strings and using `innerHTML` as that will lose you any event listeners potentially attached to the elements you wrap.

```js
const details = document.querySelectorAll('.details');

for (const detail of details) {
  const [ first, ...childrenToWrap ] = [...detail.children];
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'overlay';
  detail.append(div);
  div.append(...childrenToWrap);
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="details">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1r7oGBt.png"></div>
  <p><span class="u_title">None</span>
    <span class="u_rank"></span></p>
  <dl class="u_group"><dt>Group</dt>
    <dd>User</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="u_posts"><dt>Messages</dt>
    <dd>52</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="u_scoresystem rep_zero"><dt>Score System</dt>
    <dd>0</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="u_status"><dt>Estado</dt>
    <dd>Anónimo</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy. Use `document.createElement` to create the element, add attributes, and append it to the selected element.

```
var myEl = document.createElement("div");

// Use "className" because JavaScript "class" is a reserved keyword.
myEl.className = "myClass";

// Append it
document.querySelector("div").appendChild(myEl);
```

Working live example:

```js
var myEl = document.createElement("div");

// Use "className" because JavaScript "class" is a reserved keyword.
myEl.className = "myClass";

// Append it
document.querySelector("div").appendChild(myEl);

if (!!myEl) {
  myEl.textContent = "You can append other attributes too!";
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

You can add it as a parent element too:

```
var currentEl = document.querySelector("div");
currentEl.outerHTML = `<div class="myClass">${currentEl.outerHTML}</div>`;
```

You can append many other attributes too.

Read more about `createElement` at *[Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)*.

Comment: how would the OP select only what they want to wrap?, your answer is not addressing the issue but simply pointing out createElement

Answer (score -2):

I think you need something like this:

```
let messages = 52;
let score = 0;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',`
  <div class="details">
    <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1r7oGBt.png"></div><div class="overlay">
    <p><span class="u_title">None</span>
    <span class="u_rank"></span></p>
    <dl class="u_group"><dt>Group</dt><dd>User</dd></dl>
    <dl class="u_posts"><dt>Messages</dt><dd>${messages}</dd></dl>
    <dl class="u_scoresystem rep_zero"><dt>Score System</dt><dd>${score}</dd></dl>
    <dl class="u_status"><dt>Estado</dt><dd>Anónimo</dd></dl></div></div>
`);
```

In the above code, as you can see, you can insert messages and score dynamically to the string and also you can add the HTML dynamically using JavaScript to the body of your html document.

Comment: OP doesn't want to place the content at top of body